# Deploy website on iis using VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to deploy multiple websites on IIS using a single task in VSTS. 
How to achieve this? Using a release definition i included a task which deploys the website on IIS. But in this arrangement,i need to create as many tasks,as many websites are there. what are the ways in which i can use either a JSON file or something and create a single task which reads the website names and port numbers etc from the Json and deploys all websites in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn’t the official task that can deploy web apps together, you can create the build task through VSTS extension: [Add a build task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-build-task).

You can refer to the source code of [IIS Web App Deployment Using WinRM](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-rm-extensions/tree/master/Extensions/IISWebAppDeploy/Src) extension to build a task extension.